# Redirect touch events from one div to another jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple `ol` and list elements. The `ol` has a hard-coded height so that I can swipe/scroll through the `li` elements.

I have an overlay `div`, and I'd like to transfer all touch events to the `ol#number-swiper-column-2` element so that I can scroll through it using touch.

Basically, the overlay has a ontouchstart and ontouchmove event trigger which then moves the `ol` element to the position of my finger, but I can't swipe once it appears I need to press it again.

As you can see in the code above once i touch the screen I will get the element under my thumb however I'd like to be able to scroll through it using my thumb directly without having to tap on it first.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/szx0bg47/2/) is a jsfiddle.

```js
$('.overlay').on('touchstart', function(e) {
  var xPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX - 50;
  var yPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY - 30;
  $('#myNumberContainer').css({
    'top': yPos,
    'left': xPos
  });
  //bind scroll????, bind touchmove???
});
```

```css
.number-swiper-column {
  overflow: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  height: 1.5em;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.overlay {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background: #00000010;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="overlay"></div>

<div id="myNumberContainer" style="position:absolute;z-index:10;">
  <ol class="number-swiper-column number-swiper-column-2" id="number-swiper-column-2" data-column="2" style="top: -20px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px;">
    <li class="number-swiper-active-number">Hilario</li>
    <li class="">Jenn</li>
    <li class="">Joan</li>
    <li class="">Keith</li>
    <li class="">Raycel</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working on my Galaxy S4 - it scrolls without the need to tap it first...

Comment: These are just the respective snippets, the whole code is too big. Basically the myNumberContainer is actually hidden, and it shows when overlay detects a touch then appears under my finger. I tried using scrollTo, but it's not exactly what I want.

Basically, when I drag the overlay I want the myNumberContainer to be dragged using touch, so it's basically relaying the touch events onto another container.

Comment: Because with the provided code the issue isn't reproducable you should edit your question and add more code for example the overlay...

Comment: OK, I added a prototype of what I'm trying. Just tap anywhere within the square. You can see the text popping up, but it's not directly draggable

Comment: Your overlay has no closing tag. Is `#myNumberContainer` a child of it?

Comment: Fixed it's absolute anyway.

Comment: Isn't reproducable - even the fiddle is working on my S4...

Comment: so if you touch anywhere withing the square can you also scroll trough the list automatically?

Comment: yes - it does...

Comment: Ok, updated the jsfiddle, try now......